# HTML form input pattern with letters and æ, ø, å

Tags: html, regex, forms

I am trying to write a pattern for my HTML input form. I need to accept all letters (both upper and lower case) including the special characters æ,ø and å (and Æ, Ø, Å). I also need to accept "-" and whitespace.

Comment: Any input you are not accepting?

Comment: Anything other than mentioned.. numbers and any other characters (e.g. !"#¤%&/()=?).

Comment: Try `^[\p{L}\s-]+$`.

Comment: I have tried a lot, but nothing really seems to work like expected. I am currently using "/^(\D)+$/" which leaves numbers out, but is accepting characters like & or #..

Answer (score 2):

You can use a character class to define what characters you accept. `^[a-zA-ZæøåÆØÅ\s\-]*$`. In it, `a-z` and `A-Z` being the standard English alphabet and then the characters you want extra. You could avoid repeating the case-sensitive characters by using case-insensitive flag.

Alternatively, you could use the Unicode letter character class for all letters, including special characters of other languages. `^[\p{L}\s-]+$`

Comment: Both these still seems to accept characters like !#"¤&%()?

Comment: That shoudn't be the case, as seen https://regex101.com/r/xT0rK5/1 . Besides, you define what you accept, so anything not in the brackets is not accepted.

Comment: not sure why but when I use the attribute patten in HTML5 it can't handle if I write æøå but it accept a single æ, ø or å

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time guys, but I found "^[a-zA-Z-æøåÆØÅ]+$" to work exactly like I wanted to.

Comment: Doesn't accept whitespace, it's not what you asked in the question.